# How can i restric listbox to single select in asp.net MVC3,razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Iam using ASP.Net MVC3 Razor, I have two listboxes in .cshtml, let's say lbox1 and lbox2. I have binded data in the controller and sent to listboxes using viewbag. Both the listboxes have same data in it like A,B,C,D.But we can select more than one items from the listbox.. Now i want lbox1 selectionmode as single.
How can i restric it to single select ???

I have a controller where i binded the data

```
public Actionresult Index()
{
    ViewBag.lbox1= new SelectList(db.boxes, "ID", "Name");
}
```

This is my view

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    @Html.ListBox("lbox1")

    </td>
    <td>

    @Html.ListBox("lbox2")
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

could any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Use a DropDown instead of a ListBox:

```
@Html.DropDown("lbox1")
```

Comment: But I want items to be displayed in listbox only, and must be able to select single item.

Comment: This is not possible. There's no such element in HTML. You will need to use javascript to restrict the selection to a single element in a `<select multiple="multiple">` box which kind of defeats the purpose of using a multiple select list box. The DropDown is what has been meant to be used in this case.